# Ansible & Vagrant - give args to ansible provision

Tags: vagrant, ansible, provisioning

A collegeau of mine wrote a script to automate Vagrant installations, to include Ansible scripts. So if I run `ansible provision`, the playbook ansible/playbooks/provision.yml` is run at the vagrant machine(s).

The downside of this script is the Ansible playbook will only deploy on the machine with `ansible provision`.

Now, as I'm writing code and working, I am noticing the downsides. Because I can give `ansible-playbook` parameters / arguments, such as`ansible-playbook -i inventory provision.yml -vvv --tags "test"`. But this is not possible because of an architectual problem.

So, instead of solving the real problem (which I try to evade), are there any guru's out there, who can point me in the right directoin, to make it possible to give ansible provision arguments? E.g. `ansible provision -vvv`.

I looked at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/provision.html but without help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completly sure I have understood correctly but maybe this config (from one of my projects), in vagrantfile, could help :

```
 config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"
        ansible.limit = 'all'
        ansible.tags = 'local'
        ansible.sudo = true
        ansible.verbose = 'v'
        ansible.groups = {
          "db" => ["db"],
          "app" => ["app"],
          "myproject" => ["myproject"],
          "fourth" => ["fourth"],
          "local:children" => ["db", "app", "myproject", "fourth"]
        }
    end
```

In this Vagrantfile, I configured 4 VM vagrant.

vagrant_ansible_inventory looks like this :

```
# Generated by Vagrant

db ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
app ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
myproject ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2201 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
fourth ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2202 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key

[db]
db

[app]
app

[myproject]
myproject

[fourth]
fourth

[local:children]
db
app
myproject
fourth
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html